# rapidxml first_attribute registering a '/' as a '}'

Tags: c++, parsing, rapidxml

Okay so I have to be missing something pretty obvious but I have yet to find cause of this issue. I have a xml file that contains information about a systems units. Originally, I was saving the units in another location of the file and parsing the units worked. In this case "m/s²". I am in the process of saving unit information in another location in the file but for what ever reason the parsing, at least associated with rapidXml::first_attribute(...), is registering the "m/s²" as "m}s²". it appears that the person before ran across the issues before as they have a SomeString.Replace('}','/') call but was hoping to not mask the issue.

[image]

I have tried other characters instead of the '/' and it only seems to alter this character.

As I mentioned earlier it does did work in other location within the file so I am thinking it is some setting that I am not aware of as a lot of the code was copied from my original unit saving/loading procedure.

Comment: Can you try and make a smaller test program? Basically, just main, and use rapidxml on a small xml file